# how to detect line number of output of shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am using below script ,

```
clear
tput cup 1
echo "1";
tput cup 2
echo "2";
tput cup 4
echo "3";
```

then Out put is coming like

```
1
2
3
```

If i use wrong script like ,

```
clear
tput cup 1
echo "1";
tput cup 2
echo ;"2";
tput cup 3
echo "3";
```

then out put is

```
1

3/var.sh: line 5: 2: command not found
```

This means in third line 3 printed and 2 line error also printed .
So is there any  way to detect error line number to print 3 after error?

**EDIT:**

when I use -x , output is

```
[root@srinivas Installation]# sh -x  var.sh 
+ clear







+ tput cup 1
+ echo 1
+ echo
+ echo 3up 2
3 2
[root@srinivas Installation]#  found
+ tput cup 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run your shell script with the `-x` option, it'll show you each line as it executes.

Comment: i don't want see line numbers by using debug , when script printing out put ,it needs to print one by one line ,but in this case it is coming same line

Answer (score 0):

This is because standard output and standard error are printed in different ways - Standard output is synchronous, meaning the lines will be printed in sequence and as they arrive, while standard error is asynchronous, which means it's printed whenever the terminal can fit it in. One way to fix this is to chunk standard error together with standard output:

```
/var.sh 2>&1
```

More details in [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/106).

PS: All the semicolons in the file are unnecessary - If your commands are separated by newlines, semicolons will never be necessary.

Comment: # ./var.sh 2>&1

1
3/var.sh: line 5: 2: command not found
--------
But i need out put like
1

error**********
3

Answer (score 0):

That output looks like what should be expected. Here's the sequence:

```
tput cup 1
echo "1"
```

Move to line 1 and output a 1. This works properly.

```
tput cup 2
echo ;"2";
```

Move to line 2, then output a blank line (`echo` with no arguments) which moves to line 3. Then execute a program named `2`, which the script can't find, resulting in the error message `./var.sh: line 5: 2: command not found` printed on line 3.

```
tput cup 3
echo "3";
```

Move to line 3 and output a 3, which overwrites the `.` in the above error message. Resulting in the final apparent output that you note, even though it wasn't produced in a strictly left-to-right top-to-bottom order.

Comment: is there any auto increment line numbers process when this type errors came to the coming execute commands .

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you want. If you want the error output to not be overwritten by subsequent commands, then don't use `tput cup ...` to reposition the cursor. Just allow further commands to provide their output on the next line after the error...